# JavaScript совпадения

Tags: javascript

```
var dict = ['когда', 'сколько'
];//добавим вопросы

var ans = ['сегодня', '18:50'
];//добавим ответы   

client.on('message', msg => {
  const index = dict.indexOf(msg.body.toLowerCase());// будем хранить запросы в нижнем регистре
  if (index > -1) { // то есть такой элемент есть в массиве
    msg.reply(ans[index]);
  }
  
});
```

Когда мы спрашиваем: «когда поезд?» мы не получаем ответ -сегодня, но получаем когда пишем слово «когда» что посоветуете ?

Comment: Посоветую по-человечески задать вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно частичное совпадение, а точнее вхождение элемента массива как части в вопрос пользователя, попробуйте использовать [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) вместе с [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var dict = ['когда', 'сколько']; // добавим вопросы

var ans = ['сегодня', '18:50']; // добавим ответы

client.on('message', msg => {
  const index = dict.findIndex(
    question => msg.body.toLowerCase().includes(question.toLowerCase())
  ); // будем хранить запросы в нижнем регистре
  
  if (index > -1) { // то есть такой элемент есть в массиве
    msg.reply(ans[index]);
  }
});
```